# compile ExcelFormat Library

Tags: c++, linux

Could someone tell me how to solve this issue. I'm trying to compile this library here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library

I'm doing: `g++ Examples.cpp`

`gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`

If my question is to easy/basic/simple/os dependent... please tell recommend me a book or two that I should read first in order to be able to figure out an answer for this question.

Here's the error message:

/tmp/cczceVBy.o: In function `example1(char const*)':
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to`YExcel::BasicExcel::BasicExcel()'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `YExcel::BasicExcel::New(int)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to`YExcel::BasicExcel::GetWorksheet(int)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `ExcelFormat::XLSFormatManager::XLSFormatManager(YExcel::BasicExcel&)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to`YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(int, int)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `YExcel::BasicExcelCell::Set(char const*)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to`YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(int, int)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `YExcel::BasicExcelCell::Set(char const*)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to`YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(int, int)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x2a2): undefined reference to `YExcel::BasicExcelCell::Set(char const*)'
Examples.cpp:(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to`YExcel::BasicExcelWorksheet::Cell(int, int)'

---- snip many more of the same kind -----

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Didn't you just fortget the library for linking?

Comment: You need to add `-lsomename` to the compile-line. `somename` should match the `libsomename.lib` that the library is contained in.

Answer (score 0):

Use BasicExcel.Cpp and BasicExcel.hpp file in your project directory which comes with the Excelformat zip file.